# How are these two monomials $u_1u_2^2$ and $u_2u_3^2$ in the same orbit?

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-polynomials

From Artin's Algebra:

> A polynomial is symmetric if two monomials that are in the same orbit, such as $u_1u_2^2$ and $u_2u_3^2$, have the same coefficient in $g$.

How are the two monomials $u_1u_2^2$ and $u_2u_3^2$ in the same orbit? I don't seem to understand.

If we have $g(u_1,u_2, u_3)=u_1u_2^2+u_2u_3^2$, then $u_1u_2^2$ and $u_2u_3^2$ have the same coefficient, but $g$ is not symmetric.

Comment: Because $u_1u_2^2$ and $u_2u_1^2$ don't.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Can you please elaborate? How are the two monomials $u_1u_2^2$ and $u_2u_2^3$ in the same orbit?

Comment: If you have $n$ indeterminates, then $S_n$ acts on them, and so also on their monomials.

Comment: The permutation $(1 \ 2 \ 3)$ sends $u_1 u_2^2$ to $u_2 u_3^2$.

Comment: So, $u_1u_2^2$ and $u_2u_2^3$ are in the same orbit because the permutation $(123)$ permutes takes the monomial $u_1u_2^2$ to $u_2u_2^3$?

Comment: But in the polynomial $g(u_1,u_2, u_3)=u_1u_2^2+u_2u_3^2$, we see that $u_1u_2^2$ and $u_2u_3^2$ have the same coefficient. But $g$ is not symmetric. So, what is wrong here?

Comment: For example, under another permutation $(1 ~ 2)$, $u_1 u_2^2$ is sent to $u_1^2 u_2$, but the coefficient of the first in $g$ is 1 whereas the coefficient of the second is 0.

Answer (score 1):

In relation to the question about the $u_1 u_2^2$ and $u_2 u_3^2$ being in the same orbit:

Consider the group action of the symmetric group $S_3$ acting on the polynomials of the ring $R[x_1, x_2, x_3]$
$$ \star : S_3 \times R[x_1, x_2, x_3] \rightarrow R[x_1, x_2, x_3] $$

Where this action is defined for some $\sigma \in S_3$ and $f(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in R[x_1, x_2, x_3] $
$$ \sigma \star f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = f(x_{\sigma(1)}, x_{\sigma(2)}, x_{\sigma(3)}) $$

Then the orbit of $x_1 x_2^2$ is the set $\{\sigma \star x_1 x_2^2 : \sigma \in S_3 \} = \{x_{\sigma(1)} x_{\sigma(2)}^2 : \sigma \in S_3 \} $ then expanding this to individual terms the orbit is
$$ \{x_1 x_2^2,\, x_2 x_3^2,\, x_1 x_3^2,\, x_3 x_2^2,\, x_2 x_1^2,\, x_3 x_1^2\} $$

As this is every permutation of $S_3$ acting on $x_1 x_2^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The cyclic permutation $(1\,2\,3)$ transforms $u_1u_2^2$ into $u_2u_3^2$ so these monomials are in the same orbit of the action of the symmetric group on the monomials. But a symmetric polynomial needs to be invariant under every permutation of the variables, not just one: the quote from Artin should be read as "a polynomial is symmetric if **every** pair of monomials in the same orbit has the same coefficient".

Answer (score 0):

You have $g(u_1,u_2, u_3)=u_1u_2^2+u_2u_3^2$ but they are only **two** of the $6$ monomials in the same orbit. The quote should have stated

> A polynomial is symmetric iff **any** two monomials that are in the same orbit, such as $u_1u_2^2$ and $u_2u_2^3$ have the same coefficient $g$, including $0$.